# C# - Convert double value to [8 byte IEEE floating point] AND back again

Tags: c#, double, byte, ieee-754

Hope you can help me with this problem.

I am working for a client and in his technical notes I need to **SEND** a **double value** to a ***IEEE Floating 8byte point*** in C#. This is just the one part, after that I need to be able to **RECEIVE** a IEEE Floating 8byte point and extract the double from it.

> The specific value that I am receiving is 19500.00.

I have been searching the net a while, but think my Google skills left me hanging!

Any help will be appreciated, but code will be preferred.

Comment: How are you sending/receiving this value? As a byte array?

Comment: Seems like a trick question, a `double` in C# is already an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

Comment: How do i get a byte[8] instead of a double? I think my main problem is that I do not know how it looks when it is a byte[8]. This will certainly help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple:

> double value = 19500.00;
>
> *This gives the bytes:*
>
> > **var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);**
>
> *This gives the double again:*
>
> > **var value = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 0);**